# File Write Attempt Silently Fails - Permissions Problem

Tags: python, file

I am attempting to write a small portion of text to an (as yet) non-existing file to an directory owned by the root user and group. I have had a look at the Python docs [regarding checking if a user is authorised](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories) to write files - the code below reflects the doc example.

Here's the offending bit of code:

```
try:
    out = open('/owned/by/root/somefile.txt', 'w')
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EACCESS:
        print('Cannot write file due to permission error')
    raise
else:
    out.write('Some text content here')
    out.close()
```

Upon running this code (even as root user), no error is printed to the terminal and no exception is raised; yet the file is never actually written to the directory.

Comment: If you put a print call at the very top of the code, does it print? (I.e. are you viewing the program's stdout correctly?)

Comment: What OS are you on? Do you have any special security settings? What version of Python?

Comment: Have you tried using `access`, as specified in the [2.4 docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/os-file-dir.html), even though the current docs recommend against using it?

Comment: Also, are you doing this from the command line by running your script, or inside a graphical or text interactive interpreter? What's the answer to @katrielalex's question?

Comment: Python version is 2.7.1, OS is CentOS 5 (2.6.18-238.12.1.el5)

Comment: @agf You are on the money. Script was being run via command line. A print line at the top of the script produced no output. As for special security settings... SELinux! SELinux prevented the script from running at all without giving me any messages. Thanks guys!

Comment: You should post that as an answer (it was amalgamated from what both me and @katriel said, or I would post it) and accept it after two days.

Comment: @eryksun It is indeed EACCES - it appears that there may be a typo in the Python docs

Answer (score 0):

EACCESS should be EACCES (derived from the standard unix C libs.) That wouldn't cause you not to see an error however as IOERROR would get raised and you're re-raising even if the if block doesn't execute. This sounds like a linux specific issue. Probably SELinux.

BTW a context manager would be useful to avoid the specific else close().